# Minimum difference between consecutive multiples of $k$ that are $k\text{-rough}$

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, prime-gaps

A $k$-rough integer is any integer whose prime factors are all greater than or equal to $k$.

Is there a known formula for the smallest possible difference between consecutive $k$-rough multiples of $k$ when $k$ is prime? I've so far been unable to produce or locate one.

Comment: is there a formula for the primes greater than $k$ ?

Comment: $k$-rough. $\quad$ $k-$rough $\quad$  $k-\text{rough}$ $\quad$ $k\text{-rough}$ $\quad$ Does it need to be explained that the first and last forms above could be considered correct and the others cannot? I edited the subject line of this question. I have frequently seen people write $\sigma-$algbebra here, where $\sigma$-algebra would make sense, and then they just leave it there. Do they fail to see what it looks like, or does even that fail to tell them?

Comment: breathe boy breathe.

Comment: $2k{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k=2$ the answer is $2$.

For prime $k\ge3$, $k$-rough multiples of $k$ must be odd so must differ by at least $2k$.

Let $k\#$ be the product of all primes up to and including $k$. Then $k\#-k$ and $k\#+k$ are both $k$-rough, multiples of $k$, and differ by $2k$.